# How to use anchor box priors in yolov2?

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I saw the paper in yolov2 where they said they picked some anchor boxes to start with. But the output also predicts  a the position, width and height of the box. So there's no way to make the neural network to output boxes of that size right at the beginning. And in the implementations that I've found the output is fit to the ground truth for every sample. So it's still not using the selected anchor boxes. So why do we need anchor boxes at all?